# Android - Java connection through wifi

Tags: java, android, network-programming, network-protocols

I want to create a Java application that connects to my android phone, accesses my phones messages, files and .. That I could send or download photos, or send messages directly from my pc. What connection should I use that I would be capable to do all these things?

Comment: You mean, something like AirDroid?  https://www.airdroid.com/

Comment: Yes. Ihave already created this application using java socket